# Installing Celery with Django

Tags: django, celery

I'm trying to install [celery](/questions/tagged/celery) with [django](/questions/tagged/django) and I'm get the following error:

```
from celery.task import sets

ImportError: cannot import name sets
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a newer version of `celery` might work. Or your install might not be complete.

But `sets` should be a part of `celery.task`.

Atleast, the latest docs indicate that this should be the case: http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.task.sets.html

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ask/celery/issues#issue/315

looks like an issue that has been reported.

You might be interested in these 2 pages of the #celery irc log

> http://botland.oebfare.com/logger/celery/2011/3/4/2/
>   http://botland.oebfare.com/logger/celery/2011/3/4/3/